# MySQL query times out on the server when it shouldn't take that much time

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, hour

I have a database with records of certain sales for each day in a store. Obviously, multiple sales can happen each day and two of the fields that are recorded are the date (datetime) on which the sale happened and the price (double) of it.

I'm trying to get a granular set of data which represents the amount/sum of the prices of all sales that happened after midnight, devided by the hour. To clarify, here's a query that works and pulls out the current sum for the hours from 00:00 to 05:00:

```
SELECT DATE(date), ROUND(SUM(price), 2) FROM `table` WHERE HOUR(date) >= 0 AND HOUR(date) < 5 GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

So far so good but the first problem here is that if there's a certain day where there were no sales at all after midnight, this date is not present in the result at all and I would like to at least show 0 or NULL there. 
The other problem that I have is that I need more granular data as I need to show amounts for all sales that happened from 00:00 to 01:00, then from 01:00 to 02:00 and so forth. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT DATE(ts.date),
(SELECT ROUND(SUM(ts1.price), 2) FROM `table` ts1 WHERE HOUR(ts1.date) >= 0 AND HOUR(ts1.date) < 1 AND DATE(ts1.date) = DATE(ts.date) GROUP BY DATE(ts1.date)) AS f0to1,
(SELECT ROUND(SUM(ts2.price), 2) FROM `table` ts2 WHERE HOUR(ts2.date) >= 1 AND HOUR(ts2.date) < 2 AND DATE(ts2.date) = DATE(ts.date) GROUP BY DATE(ts2.date)) AS f1to2,
(SELECT ROUND(SUM(ts3.price), 2) FROM `table` ts3 WHERE HOUR(ts3.date) >= 2 AND HOUR(ts3.date) < 5 AND DATE(ts3.date) = DATE(ts.date) GROUP BY DATE(ts3.date)) AS f2to3,
(SELECT ROUND(SUM(ts4.price), 2) FROM `table` ts4 WHERE HOUR(ts4.date) >= 0 AND HOUR(ts4.date) < 5 AND DATE(ts4.date) = DATE(ts.date) GROUP BY DATE(ts4.date)) AS allhours
FROM `table` ts WHERE 1 GROUP BY DATE(ts.date)
```

This query, however, times out on the server and I'm not sure why as it shouldn't take that long. The database that I'm working with has about 5-6k records and a timespan for a couple of months so I'm looking at about 60 rows in the result table. Any ideas how to restructure the query and make it more efficient or suggestions on other approaches (joins, unions, etc)?

P.S. The table name is different from 'table', I just changed it for simplicity here.

Comment: I think the title clearly states MySQL thus the server is indeed MySQL.

Comment: Then why tag sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you want to achieve can be broken down in few steps:

1. You need to get a list of all dates that you want to process. How
   you achieve this depends on your database, you will easily find the
   way. Here is example - http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

   In Sql Server you can put SQL that generates dates in CTE statement
2. Take your working query and LEFT JOIN it to dates set.

Hope that helps.